# Django Model data filter

Tags: django, model

This is an initial attempt to setup some basic CRUD functionality for an existing database (SQL Server based) for an internal Django App. I would like advice on model definitions that would support a primary table that holds a list of Trading Partners and also identifies a Partner Type. A Partner can in fact have a number of types. For example a Customer could also be a Supplier. There is then a related table of PartnerTypes that provides some extra details but primarily a Textual Description/Name assigned to the Partner Type.

When I used the inspectdb command from Django I got what one would expect and the ForeignKeys were setup in the model.

I would like to know is it possible to include some type of 'filtering' with in the Model Class to utilise the same table across different Classes.

For example create a Model Class for a Client (eg. Client_Partner) and then another for a Supplier (eg. Supplier_Partner) have them both point to the same underlying Partner table and yet allow for the generation of a separate form for each 'Type' of partner?

During the Creation of a New Client then the TypeID would need to be prefilled with the appropriate TypeId.

I understand that it may be more appropriate to not use the Admin Interface but as I an new to Django and this is an internal project I thought it might be possible to 'hit the ground running' and get some data entry going against a set of largely static master data tables.

Thanks in advance
(I'm afraid I learn best from examples so whilst I have read through many posts and some of the doco I still feel lost without something I can follow in the form of a basic example)

Example Table Data (In this case Company A is both a Client and a Supplier)

```
+--------+-----------------------+---------+
| TypeID | Type                  | Code    |
+--------+-----------------------+---------+
| 0      | Parent                | PARENT  |
| 1      | Client                | CLI     |
| 2      | Supplier              | SUPP    |
+--------+-----------------------+---------+

+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----------+
| PartnerID | name               | TypeID | Code      |
+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----------+
| 1         | Our Company        | 0      | US        |
| 10        | Company A          | 1      | CA        |
| 20        | Company A          | 2      | CA        |
| 30        | Company B          | 2      | CB        |
+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----------+
```

Generated Django Model

```
class Trading_Partner(models.Model):
    partnerid = models.IntegerField(db_column='PartnerID', primary_key=True) 
    code = models.CharField(db_column='Code', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    typeid = models.ForeignKey('Trading_Partner_Type', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='TypeID', blank=True, null=True)
    lei = models.CharField(db_column='LEI', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True) 

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Partner'


class Trading_Partner_Type(models.Model):
    typeid = models.IntegerField(db_column='TypeID', primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(db_column='Code', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PartnerType'
```

Comment: drf have nice example on how to write [nested](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) serializers, all I can say that I would rather start extending that models and go in that direction.

Comment: Thanks very much for this reply. A little out of my current skill set at the moment. But will take a better look when I am confident to do so as it seemed to be a possible if not probable solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distinguish the different types of partner, you can use [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

```
class PartnerManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, partner_type):
        super().__init__()
        self.partner_type = partner_type

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(typeid=self.partner_type)

class Client_Partner(Trading_Partner):
    objects = PartnerManager(1)
    class Meta(Trading_Partner.Meta):
        proxy = True

class Parent_Partner(Trading_Partner):
    objects = PartnerManager(0)
    class Meta(Trading_Partner.Meta):
        proxy = True

class Supplier_Partner(Trading_Partner):
    objects = PartnerManager(2)
    class Meta(Trading_Partner.Meta):
        proxy = True
```

But I don't know if this is possible with unmanaged models.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I would like to accept your reply as the answer. Whilst I have not implemented your suggestion as yet I have taken a look at the doco and your snippet and I can see how it could possibly fit. In this case I took a 'cheats' way out as I had the luxury of being able to adjust the underlying table structure. In our case I was able to establish a similar pattern by having a table for each of the partner types and a mix of foreign keys. Downstream I can cleanup user views by creating back-end database views that links things up. Thanks again